# Como Obtener un token de authenticacion, solo enviando el userName(Directorio Activo)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, directorioactivo

Tengo mi código que genera el apiToken, pero este requiere un userName y password, funciona correctamente si se le envía los datos correctos, lo que quiero lograr es que me genere ese token pero solo con el usuario del directorio activo, porque de echo se me ha sido imposible obtener la contraseña, entonces solo le estoy enviando mi userName y así no me lo genera; alguna solución o recomendación para poder lograr lo que quiero?

```
 public async Task<string> GetApiTokenAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Setup Cliente
            var apiBaseUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiBaseUri"].ToString();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var result = await client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + userName + "&password=" + password, Encoding.UTF8));

            //get acces token from response body
            var responseJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseJson;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tal ves podamos ayudarte mejor si amplias la explicación de lo que quieres hacer